# Erro: type 'ListarPedido' is not a subtype of type 'Itens'

Tags: flutter, dart

Trecho do código Model:

```
  int numero;
  String localEntrega;
  String dataHora;
  String formaPagamento;
  List<Itens> itens;

  ListarPedido(
      {this.numero,
      this.localEntrega,
      this.dataHora,
      this.formaPagamento,
      this.itens});

  ListarPedido.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    numero = json['numero'];
    localEntrega = json['local_entrega'];
    dataHora = json['data_hora'];
    formaPagamento = json['forma_pagamento'];
    if (json['Itens'] != null) {
      itens = new List<Itens>();
      json['Itens'].forEach((v) {
        itens.add(new Itens.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['numero'] = this.numero;
    data['local_entrega'] = this.localEntrega;
    data['data_hora'] = this.dataHora;
    data['forma_pagamento'] = this.formaPagamento;
    if (this.itens != null) {
      data['Itens'] = this.itens.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Itens {
  String itemUid;
  String qtde;
  String valor;
  String valorTotal;
  String descrProduto;
  String tamanho;
  String textoOpc;

  Itens(
      {this.itemUid,
      this.qtde,
      this.valor,
      this.valorTotal,
      this.descrProduto,
      this.tamanho,
      this.textoOpc});

  Itens.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    itemUid = json['item_uid'];
    qtde = json['qtde'];
    valor = json['valor'];
    valorTotal = json['valor_total'];
    descrProduto = json['descr_produto'];
    tamanho = json['tamanho'];
    textoOpc = json['texto_opc'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['item_uid'] = this.itemUid;
    data['qtde'] = this.qtde;
    data['valor'] = this.valor;
    data['valor_total'] = this.valorTotal;
    data['descr_produto'] = this.descrProduto;
    data['tamanho'] = this.tamanho;
    data['texto_opc'] = this.textoOpc;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Trecho do código da API via POST:

```
import 'package:cardapiomonitor/api/listar_pedido.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import '../functions/fn_utils.dart';

class ListarPedidoApi {
  static Future<List<ListarPedido>> getListarPedido() async {
    var url = "http://192.168.1.12/api/ws_acoes.php";
    String lppeduuid = prefs.getString("PedUuid");

    var response = await http.post(
      url,
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: <String, String>{
        'pedido': lppeduuid,
        'requisicao': 'LISTARPEDIDO',
      },
    );

    List listaResponseLP = json.decode(response.body);

    List<Itens> itens = List<Itens>();

    final listarpedidos = List<ListarPedido>();
    // final listarpedidositens = List<Itens>();
    // List<Itens> listarpedidositens = List<Itens>();

    for (Map mapLP in listaResponseLP) {
      ListarPedido lp = ListarPedido.fromJson(mapLP);
      listarpedidos.add(lp);

      Itens lpi = Itens.fromJson(mapLP);
      itens.add(lpi);
    }

    return listarpedidos;
  }
}
```

Trecho do código:

```
_body() {
    Future<List<ListarPedido>> listarpedidos =
        ListarPedidoApi.getListarPedido();
    return RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: _getDataListarPedidos,
      backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: listarpedidos,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text(
                "Seu token está errado.",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                ),
              ),
            );
          }

          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }

          List<ListarPedido> listarpedidos = snapshot.data;
          return _listView(listarpedidos);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  _listView(listarpedidos) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: listarpedidos != null ? listarpedidos.length : 0,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        ListarPedido lp = listarpedidos[index];

        return SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(2, 20, 2, 15),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(
                  Icons.add_shopping_cart_rounded,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                title: Text(
                  "Número do Pedido: " + lp.numero.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(
                  Icons.attach_money,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                title: Text(
                  "Local de Entrega: " + lp.localEntrega,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(
                  Icons.format_size,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                title: Text(
                  "Data e Hora: " + lp.dataHora,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(
                  Icons.format_size,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                title: Text(
                  "Forma de Pagamento: " + lp.formaPagamento,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Divider(
                color: Colors.red[600],
                height: 20,
                thickness: 3,
                indent: 20,
                endIndent: 20,
              ),
              _itens(),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  _itens() {
    Future<List<ListarPedido>> listarpedidos =
        ListarPedidoApi.getListarPedido();
    return RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: _getDataListarPedidos,
      backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: listarpedidos,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text(
                "Seu token está errado.",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                ),
              ),
            );
          }

          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }

          List<ListarPedido> listarpedidos = snapshot.data;
          return _itensView(listarpedidos);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  _itensView(listarpedidos) {
    return ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: listarpedidos != null ? listarpedidos.length : 0,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        Itens lpi = listarpedidos[index];

        return SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(2, 20, 2, 15),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(
                  Icons.location_on,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                title: Text(
                  lpi.itemUid,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 0,
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(
                  Icons.date_range,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                title: Text(
                  "Quantidade: " + lpi.qtde,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(
                  Icons.credit_card,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                title: Text(
                  "Valor: " + lpi.valor,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(
                  Icons.location_on,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                title: Text(
                  "Valor Total: " + lpi.valorTotal,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(
                  Icons.location_on,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                title: Text(
                  "Descrição Produto: " + lpi.descrProduto,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(
                  Icons.location_on,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                title: Text(
                  "Tamanho: " + lpi.tamanho,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(
                  Icons.location_on,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                title: Text(
                  "Opcionais: " + lpi.textoOpc,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

E eu recebo esse erro:

```
type 'ListarPedido' is not a subtype of type 'Itens'
```

Porque da esse erro???

Comment: Esse erro ocorre porque você está tentando alimentar uma variável do tipo `Itens` com algum outro valor do tipo `ListarPedido`... O problema possivelmente é aqui `Itens lpi = listarpedidos[index];` você precisa mudar para `Itens lpi = listarpedidos[index][0];` (Ou outro valor diferente de 0.

Comment: Recebi estte erro: Class 'ListarPedido' has no instance method '[]'.
Receiver: Instance of 'ListarPedido'
Tried calling: [](0)

Comment: Ops foi falta de atenção, de uma olhadinha... Do que falei faltou o nome da propriedade, na verdade é `Itens lpi = listarpedidos[index].itens[0];

Comment: Deu certo aqui, muito obrigado, só que da lista de itens só ta trazendo uma lsita, você teria alguma sugestão?

Comment: Daí é você quem tem que resolver, vai de acordo com a lógica de como pretende exibir os itens... Você teria que percorrer todos os itens da lista e ir exibindo cada um na tela.